# WD 14TB EasyStore doesn't spin up both inside the enclosure and outside of enclosure

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a WD 14TB Easystore which stopped spinning up in it's enclosure for no apparent reason. Disk Management would show it but give "fatal error" when trying to assign a letter.

I removed the drive from the enclosure, tried it with and without the 3.3v pin mod across multiple SATA ports and it's showing no signs of life. I've never had a drive fail like this for no apparent reason, usually there's some clicking noises or grinding etc but this seems to fail to power up at all.

Is there any way to fix the drive or anything else to try? I had some files on there which weren't worth paying £1k for a data recovery service but I'd still like to have back.

Comment: *anything else to try?* Can you check a diode? If so, search for "disk drive TVS diode" and hope.

Comment: If you are "lucky" and only popped the hard drive's circuit board, you may be able to replace it like https://www.hddzone.com/western_digital_pcb_swap_replacement.html, though it's usually better to have a data recovery place do it

Answer (score 0):

See [@Andrew Morton's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1763447/wd-14tb-easystore-doesnt-spin-up-both-inside-the-enclosure-and-outside-of-enclo#comment2742840_1763447) to the initial question. A drive that suddenly stops spinning *may* be fixable as there's a chance the TVS diode is the culprit.

[image]

Gaining access to the data may be as simple as removing the TVS diode. To return the drive to a reliable working drive, the diode needs to be replaced. Replacing requires some soldering skills and is not recommended as a first project. But arguably you could consider this DIY-able.

See: http://www.hddoracle.com/viewtopic.php?f=100&t=86 for a detailed discussion.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YuN9H9F here is an image of the board, I can't identify the TVS diode on it. I've done some very basic soldering so this will be a tall task but my other option is to throw the drive away so I might as well give it a shot if I can identify and source a replacement.

Comment: I updated image in my answer with yours and marked TVS and 'fuse'. If TVS is the issue wit multimeter in continuity, black at the side where lines ||| are, red other side you get beep. In diode mode black at ||| red other side, if reading is close to zero TVS is bad. In which case I'd remove it, hook up drive. If it spins save data. Note that by removing the diode you removed protection as well so it's *not meant to be a permanent solution*! If fuse is shorted, remove and bridge it for *temporary* solution.

Comment: For permanent repair, ask some PC repair or electronics repair shop to do soldering for you. Specially fuse is tiny, easy to screw this up. If you rip off the pads repair is suddenly a 10 fold more difficult. If available, practice on some discarded old drives first.

Answer (score -1):

If the drive is truly dead as you say it is.  There is nothing we can suggest that will make it work.  If you want the data, then you will need to go to recovery specialist.  That being said, if its just the power that has died, then recovery should be fairly easy and therefore, hopefully inexpesive.