# How to boot from a drive that is not being recognized as bootable?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

My PSU recently made a loud noise, followed by everything shutting off, so I took it out and tested it, and it was broken. I ordered a new PSU and plugged it in and nothing else got fried! Which is super lucky. However, I am now having an issue where I am getting no bootable drives available. I plugged in my USB for installing windows and was able to get to the CMD and was able to list all of the drives. All of the drives are there and the files for one of them has bootable windows files. I also noticed that the names of these drives changed as well. I am unsure if this could be affecting things but drive A: became drive C: and drive C: became drive D: the old drive that I was booting from was drive C (now drive D). I am unsure how to proceed or what settings to change in the bios, any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have not been able to successfully boot since installing the new PSU. There are two drives one has the OS and a few files the other is a separate SSD with 1 partition. I used the connectors that came with the new PSU that I ordered

What is the best way to let the bios find the old drive that it was using to boot? Currently, there are no bootable drives even though using windows CMD I was able to view two drives.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you start in BIOS?  If so reset to defaults, restart and see if drives show up and then if you can start the machine

Comment: *I am now having an issue where I am getting no bootable drives available.* please clarify if it booted correctly following the incident then subsequently failed to boot, or never booted since the failure.  Please advise if you have more than once bootable drive or OS.  Please advise if you reordered any connectors.  Please list every drive in the system as well as a description of how they are (or were used) OS, partitions etc.

Comment: I was able to restore to the default settings and they still did not show up. @John

Comment: The incident may have stressed things so much that you need to back up and reinstall the OS.

Comment: It had not booted successfully since installing the new PSU. There was only one bootable drive and OS. I used connectors that came with the new PSU. I have edited the question to reflect this information and info about the drives @BlindSpots

Comment: There are other files on the old boot drive. Is it possible to do this without losing those files? @John

Comment: Boot from a bootable USB and see if you can recover the files that way.

Comment: Is this a spinning disk and if so, does it actually spin? It's not unthinkable your PSU adventures fried something on the PCB of the drive, most likely candidate the TVS diode (see, https://superuser.com/a/1765306/705502).

Comment: There is not a physical disk. Both drives were SSDs @JoepvanSteen

Comment: SSD's even more sensitive to this type of stuff.

Comment: an SSD **IS** a *physical disk*

Comment: Does the fact that I was able to see the files on both SSDs not prove that the drives are working and should be able to be used as a bootable drives? Or can this still happen with something like the TVS diode getting fried? @JoepvanSteen

Comment: @garrett_17, I apologize, I missed that.